# Null pointer exception at Context used in dialog class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog

I have a class thate extends a built-in dialog class, and I want to access sharedprefence in it, but having null pointer exception at that point.

**Here is my code**

```
public class DialogCancelOrder extends Dialog {

    Context context;

    public DialogCancelOrder(Context a, String orderid) {
        super(a);
        this.orderid = orderid;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("afewtaps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf");
        face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Rupee_Foradian_2.ttf");
}
```

Comment: Put context =a; in constructor

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the line  **context=a;**  Use the below code. I have assigned the value for the context in the constructor.

```
 public class DialogCancelOrder extends Dialog {

    Context context;

    public DialogCancelOrder(Context a, String orderid) {
        super(a);
        this.orderid = orderid;
        this.context = a;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("afewtaps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf");
        face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Rupee_Foradian_2.ttf");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize your `context` field. Try this in the constructor:

```
this.context = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not initialize context use this. This may help

```
public DialogCancelOrder(Context a, String orderid) {
               super(a);
                      this.orderid = orderid;
                      context=a;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't write anything into `context` variable. Then you try to use it.
Instead of declaring your own variable, you can use `this.getContext()` inside the `Dialog`